# UserDefaultsで保存した値を別のViewで読み込みたい

Tags: swift, ios

### 実現したいこと

VieControllerにあるTableVieのcellをタップするとcellに入っている情報をRegisterViewControllerで表示することは前までの質問でできたのですが、新たにListViewControllerを作りRegisterViewControllerの右上のボタンをタップするとListViewControllerのcellに表示したいです。

またViewControllerとListViewControllerはTabBar移動をできるようにしています。
RegisterViewはいわばViewControllerの付属機能となっているのでListViewControllerからNavigationへ戻ることもしたくないと思っているため、登録したらListViewControllerに情報の入ったcellは追加されるも遷移せずにそのままViewControllerにのみ戻れるようにしたいです。

### 疑問点

遷移なしで値を渡すのでUDで値のみ受け渡すですが、CustomCellのUDなのでNSCodingを使用したいと思っているので、NSKeyedUnarchiverを使用したいです。
RegisterのitemをaddListTappedされたらListViewのlistに入れてTableViewcellのlistNameLabelとlistDateLabelをxibで作っているのでそれに表示したいのですが、候補に出てこないので書き方を教えてもらいたいです。

### ソースコード

**ItemModelClass**

```
class Item : NSObject,NSCoding{
    
    var name:String
    var date:String
    
    init(name:String,date:String){
        self.name = name as String
        self.date = date as String
    }
    
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.name,forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(self.date,forKey: "date")
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        self.date = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "date") as! String
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var table:UITableView!
    var items:[Item] = [Item]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        table.register(TableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier)

        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        
        self.setupItems()
    }
    
    func setupItems(){
        items = [Item(name:"a",date:"1"),Item(name:"b",date:"2"),Item(name:"c",date:"3"),Item(name:"d",date:"4"),Item(name:"e",date:"5"),]
    }
}
以下省略
```

**RegisterViewController**

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var registeredNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var registeredDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addListButton:UIBarButtonItem!
    
    //Item型
    var item: Item!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //MovieListに追加するためのボタン
        addListButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "リストへ追加", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addListTapped(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addListButton]
        
        registeredNameLabel.text = item.name
        registeredDateLabel.text = item.date
    }
    
    @objc func addListTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        print("Tapped")
        //疑問点
}
```

**ListViewController**

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController{
    
    var list:[Item] = []
    var allList:[Item] = []
    var selectedList:[Item] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table:UITableView!
    
    @IBAction func segmentSelcted(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            list = allList
        case 1:
            list = selectedList
        default:
            fatalError("caseでカバーできません")
        }
        table.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        
        //UD読み込み
     
    }
}
extension ListViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        list.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ListTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell
        cell.setcell(item: list[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

ListTableViewCell

```
func setcell(item:Item){
        self.listNameLabel.text = item.name as String
        self.listDateLabel.text = item.date as String
    }
```

Comment: 「別のViewで」と言うのは「別のview controllerで」の意味でしょうか？iOSではview(`UIView`)とview controller(`UIViewController`)は異なる概念なので、それらをごっちゃにされると意味を取るのが大変難しくなります。＞「ViewControllerとListViewControllerはTabBar移動をできる」「Navigationへ戻ることもしたくない」いったい複数のview controllerをどのような関係で持ちたいのかがよく分かりません。`UITabBarController`、`UINavigationController`を含めて、どんなview controllerがどのように繋がっているのか、工夫して図示などしていただけないでしょうか。＞「遷移せずにそのままViewControllerにのみ戻れる」`ViewController`に戻るんならそれは「遷移」ではないんですか？＞「遷移なしで値を渡すのでUDで値のみ受け渡す」先に書いたように「遷移なし」が意味を持ちませんし、遷移がどうこうというのと「UDで値を受け渡す」と言うのが何をどう解釈してもつながりません。ちなみに「UD」は`UserDefaults`のことでしょうが、自分だけわかる省略語を使われるとこれまた質問内容が読みにくくなります。

Comment: ＞「CustomCellのUDなので…NSKeyedUnarchiverを使用したい」これまたcustom cellを使うことと`NSCoding`を使用すること`NSKeyedUnarchiver`を使用することはつながってきません。まずは、各view controller間の関係がどのようになっているのかを整理して、どのような画面遷移(tab間の切り替えも画面遷移です)の際にどんなデータを受け渡したいのかをはっきりさせるようにしてください。誤った前提や知識のもとで`UserDefaults`を使用しなければならない、`NSKeyedUnarchiver`を使用しなければならないと誤った結論を出されているように思い破れます。

Comment: 別のview controllerでの意味です。すみません。画像を追加したのですがViewControllerとListViewControllerはTabBar移動ができ、ViewControllerにあるitemsをcellに表示してdidselectされるとRegisterViewControllerに遷移されてデータをLabelで表示しているのが質問以前にできていたことです。そしてRegisterViewControllerの右上にNavigationBarにボタンを追加して、ボタンを押した時にListViewControllerのTableViewにRegisterViewControllerから受け取ったデータを表示するのが目的です。

Comment: 遷移なしというのはRegisterViewControllerはViewControllerの付属機能というかListViewControllerに値を入れるためのみの機能なので連続でViewControllerのデータをListViewに追加したいとなった時にRegisterViewControllerのボタンを押したたびにListViewControllerに遷移されるとViewControllerに戻るのにTabBar移動をしないといけないため不便だと思いRegisterViewControllerからListViewControllerは遷移なしで値のみ渡したいと思ったのでUserDefaultsを採用しました。(遷移させてしまうとListViewControllerからRegisterViewControllerにもNavigationで戻れてしまうからそれも行いたくないということです。あくまでデータのみ渡せればいいなということです。)

Comment: 以前カスタムセル(Data型)は普通のUserDefaultsでは保存できないとわかってのでNSCodingを使用したのですが今回もListViewControllerのCellはItem型のカスタムセルで作っているので使用するのかと思ったのですがNSCodingまたはCodableを使うのかと思いました。余談ですが複数の View 間でデータを共有したい場合はSingleton クラスを作ったりすることもできるそうですがまだ理解が追いついていないので今回はUserDefaultsを使用したいです。

Comment: 長いコメントに対して、丁寧に返信いただき、またご質問の更新もいただいてありがとうございました。「遷移なしで値のみ渡したい」については、だいぶ意味が伝わってきたように思います。ただし、「複数の View (controller)間でデータを共有したい場合はSingleton クラスを作ったりすることもできる」については、Singletonクラスを作った方が遥かに簡単になります。画面間のデータの受け渡しにUserDefaultsを使用するなんて言うのは、その方が簡単な場合に応急避難的に行うことがありますが、将来App Storeに載せるようなちゃんとしたアプリで行うものではありません。その上、Item型を使用しようとカスタムセルを使用しようと(両者がごっちゃになっているように見えますが)Singletonクラスで受け渡しをする(と言うよりデータを丸ごと持たせてしまう)ようにすれば、「NSCodingまたはCodableを使う」必要もありません。手抜きでUserDefaultsを使用している困ったブログ記事とかも多いので、そう言うのに染まって変な発想になっているように思われます。

Answer (score 1):

さて、コメントに書いたようにSingletonを作るのは特に難しいことではないため、「UserDefaultsで保存」と明記された質問に対する回答としては押し売り気味になりますが、

- `UserDefaults`は使用せずにSingletonを利用する

と言う方針での回答を書かせていただきます。

---

さて、iOSプログラミングを始めてまだ間がない方にとって、(`UIViewController`や`UIView`以外の)自前のクラスを定義すると言うのは、理解の追いつかない難しいことに見えるとおっしゃる方は多いのですが、習うより慣れろでやってみると、そう難しいことではないことがわかります。

基本はこんな形式のクラスを書くだけです。

```
class MyData {
    //`UserDefaults`に合わせた名前のシングルトンを定義
    static let standard = MyData()

    //その他必要な機能をここに記述する
    //...
}
```

コメントを読む限り、

- `RegisterViewController`で`ListViewController`に表示されるデータを操作

することが主眼のように見えるので、ここでは`ListViewController`の`allList`と`selectedList`を`MyData`に移してしまうことにします。

```
class MyData {
    //`UserDefaults`に合わせた名前のシングルトンを定義
    static let standard = MyData()

    //複数のview controllerからアクセスされる変数は関連性の強い変数とともにこの中にまとめる
    private(set) var allList:[Item] = []
    private(set) var selectedList:[Item] = []
    
    func add(_ item: Item, isSelected: Bool = false) {
        allList.append(item)
        if isSelected {
            selectedList.append(item)
        }
    }
    
    //`allList`の一部を`selectedList`に入れるなんて操作が必要ならこちらに定義する
    //...
}
```

- `private(set)`が付けてあるのは、いろんなところで勝手に配列操作を行われると整合性が取れなくなる可能性があるためです。
- Singletonを表すプロパティ名は`shared`とか`default`とかが人気(?)だったりしますが、同じくSingletonを使っている`UserDefaults`の使用には抵抗が無いようなので、それに合わせて`standard`にしてあります。
- コンピュータ上で扱える情報はなんでも「data」なんで、`MyData`なんて言うのはかなり最低なネーミングセンスです。実際のアプリではもうちょっとマシな名前にしてください。

---

上記の`MyData`を使うと`RegisterViewController`は次のようになります。

- 削除(して移動)すべきところが分かりやすくなるようにコメントアウトしたままにしている部分がありますが、実際にお試しになるなら不要なんでサクッと削除してください。

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var registeredNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var registeredDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addListButton:UIBarButtonItem!
    
    //Item型→可能な限りImplicitly Unwrappedにすることは避ける
    var item: Item? //<-
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //MovieListに追加するためのボタン
        addListButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "リストへ追加", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addListTapped(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addListButton]
        
        //他画面から渡ってきたデータの処理は`viewDidLoad`でなく、`viewWillAppear`で行う方が良い
//        registeredNameLabel.text = item?.name
//        registeredDateLabel.text = item?.date
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        guard let item = item else {
            print("item is nil")
            //必要なら他のエラー処理
            return
        }
        
        //他画面から渡ってきたデータの処理はここで行う
        registeredNameLabel.text = item.name
        registeredDateLabel.text = item.date
    }
    
    @objc func addListTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        print("Tapped")
        //疑問点
        guard let item = item else {
            print("item is nil")
            //必要なら他のエラー処理
            return
        }
        //`MyData`のメソッドを通じてのみデータ操作を行う
        MyData.standard.add(item, isSelected: false)
    }
}
```

- `item`のデータ型を`Item!`から`Item?`に変更してあります。`@IBOutlet`のような定形パターンを除いて、「Implicitly Unwrapped Optional(`!`)は使用しない」と覚えておくことをお勧めしておきます。

---

同じく、`ListViewController`を`MyData`使用版に差し替えるとこんな感じになります。

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //変更があるたびに配列のコピーをするのではなく、どちらか必要な配列を都度「計算」してやる
    var list: [Item] {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            return MyData.standard.allList
        case 1:
            return MyData.standard.selectedList
        default:
            fatalError("caseでカバーできません")
        }
    }
    //複数のview controllerからアクセスされる変数は関連性の強い変数とともに`MyData`に移動させる
//    var allList:[Item] = []
//    var selectedList:[Item] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    //`list`を計算型プロパティにするため、IBOutletを追加、正しく接続しておく
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    
    @IBAction func segmentSelcted(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        //`list`を計算型プロパティにすることで、ここで配列のコピーが不要になる
//        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
//        case 0:
//            list = allList
//        case 1:
//            list = selectedList
//        default:
//            fatalError("caseでカバーできません")
//        }
        //しかし、`table.reloadData()`は必要
        table.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        
        //必要なデータは全部`MyData`に入れてあるので、この時点で読み込んだりする必要はない
    }
    
    //`viewWillAppear(_:)`の中で`table.reloadData()`を呼ばないと画面が更新されない場合がある
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

- 上記の中で、`list`を計算型プロパティに書き換えている部分は必須ではありませんし、「どんな観点で見てもbetter」とは言い切れないのですが、「複数の配列を整合性を保って更新しなければいけない」と言う状態はプログラムの規模が大きくなるにつれ管理が非常に困難になってくるので、あえて入れさせていただきました。

---

ご質問中に示されたコードで省略されている部分については、この回答でも省略しましたが、それほど大きな修正は必要ないだろうと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか。

もしかしたら`UserDefaults`の使用必須と言う縛りの課題なのかもしれませんが、そうでなければ是非お試しいただきたいと思います。

Comment: Singletonにしていただきありがとうございます。計算型プロパティとは渡ってきたデータをコピーするのではなく、SegmentedControlが渡されたデータを保有し固有のデータとしてsenderされるたびに読み込むということですか？

Comment: また、またlist:[Item]はaddListTappedで直接関わってはいないようですがlistに属すallListにitemが渡されることにより、listも更新されlistのnumberOfrowInSectionやlistのindex.pathを反映させることができるということですか？コードを書き換えエラーもなく問題なくデータは渡っているとは思うのですが、ListViewControllerのTableViewは変化がありません。Viewの部分を変えないといけないと思うのですが、RegisterViewの省略していたTableViewとListTableViewCellのLabelの部分のコードを追加いたしました。自分でもやってみますが教えてもらえるとありがたいです。

Comment: @uta さん、コメントありがとうございます。「SegmentedControlが渡されたデータを保有」「固有のデータ」「senderされるたび」→全て私には意味が理解できません。`list`を計算型プロパティにすると言うことは、`list`が参照されるたびにSegmentedControlから値を拾ってきて実際に参照したい方の配列を返しているだけです。SegmentedControlにデータを渡したりもしませんし、「固有」なんて難しい単語で表現されることもしてませんし、senderは名詞(もの)なので「senderされる」が意味を持ちません。

Comment: 「またlist:[Item]はaddListTappedで直接関わってはいない…numberOfrowInSectionやlistのindex.pathを反映させることができるということですか？」正直意味がよく理解できていないのですが`list`は「更新される」のではなく、(SegmentedControlで0が選ばれている間)`allList`と必ず同じになるように計算しています。

Comment: 「ListViewControllerのTableViewは変化がありません。」追記いただいたコードでこちらのテスト用のプロジェクトを修正して試しましたが、タブをListTableViewCell側に切り替えれば普通に内容が更新されています。(ちなみに、これがうまく動かない原因というわけではないですが、`setcell(item:)`内にある`as String`は不要です。とんでもなく古いやり方をしている記事内で、同じように不要な`as String`を付けているものを見かけました。最新のXcode/Storyboardでのやり方に合わせた記事を見つけられるようにした方が良いと思います。)明示されていない設定やコードでどこが異なると、ListViewControllerへ変化が反映されなくなるのか、回答に書き漏らしたことがないかなどチェックしていますが、今のところ見つかりません。

Comment: 確認したところClassの名前を途中で変えたことによる食い違いでした、気をつけます。問題なく更新されました。MyData内での if isSelected { selectedList.append(item) }は何を表しているのでしょうか？addメソッドのところでは基本的にallListに値が渡されているのでしょうか？

Comment: また配列のコピーをする場合で似たようなものを製作したことがあるのですがその時はUserDefaultsで保存し後にself.todos = self.allTodoのように配列をコピーして保存をしていたのですが今回の場合どのすれば良いのでしょうか？今のところ再ビルドすると元の何もない状態になります。

Comment: @uta さん、 `isSelected`については、`ListViewController`の中で、`allList`が全リスト、`selectedList`が(その中で)選択されたもののリスト、と使い分けられているように見えたので、`add`メソッドで`allList`につかすると同時に選択、と言うのが簡単にできるようにしてあります。「addメソッドのところでは基本的にallListに値が渡されているのでしょうか？」メソッドの中ではっきりと`allList`を操作しているので、何がわからないのかわかりません。

Comment: 「その時はUserDefaultsで保存し」前から変なことをする癖がついているようですね。データの受け渡しと保存とをごっちゃにしないでください。「データの受け渡し」だけが必要な場合に`UserDefaults`を使う必要はありません。「今のところ再ビルドすると元の何もない状態」再ビルドしなくても、一度停止して再度実行すれば「元の何もない状態」に戻ります。何らかの方法でデータを保存したり復元したりしなければ当然そうなりますが、それはview controller間でのデータの受け渡しとは独立に考えてください。また、`UserDefaults`は、一般のデータの保存先ではなく、アプリ用の「設定」画面にあるような少数の設定情報を保存することを意図して用意されているものです。データの保存先に`UserDefaults`を使うのは簡易化された練習用のアプリでない限りやめておくべきです。

Comment: そうなのですね、まだデータの保存の使い分けや構造を理解できていないのでワンパターンな思考にしかできてません。少し自分でも見直してみます。ありがとうございました。